# Handle multiple notifications with GCM

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have basic push notifications through Google Cloud messaging working, but have trouble with multiple messages. I use basic notifications (eg. I let the system create the actual notification message) but provide an URL to be opened in my application in the data section.

Here is what I have so far:

My `MainActivity` is has an intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="GCM" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

In my `onCreate()` function I have the following:

```
Intent startIntent = getIntent();
    if (startIntent.hasExtra("url")) {
    openUrl(startIntent.getStringExtra("url"));
}
```

I send payloads that look like this:

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "..."
  ],
  "notification": {
    "body": "This is a body.",
    "title": "This is a title.",
    "icon": "app",
    "sound": "default",
    "click_action": "GCM"
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "/quiz/"
  }
}
```

So far so good. When I receive a message and click it, it opens my app and loads the URL. Problems arise when I get multiple messages:

1. When I get two message with two different URLs, I always get the URL of the first notification in my `MainActivity`. Even when I clicked on the second notification.
2. When my activity is already open and I receive a message, clicking it will not open the URL (probably because `onCreate()` isn't called then).

My guess is that both are somewhat related and that I should handle incoming messages somehow different.

Comment: From my research so far, it seems like Android is reusing the same intent for all messages by the same sender. The usual way around it would be to define the payload in data only and built notifications yourself. However this breaks compatibility with iOS. The only way around it would be sending different payloads for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use different Notification ID's for different notifications so they dont get stacked.

So when creating a sample notification like this, make sure to push notifications with **`mId`** that are different from eachother. This way each notification will show as separate. Other way you could do this is to add the URLs to a list contained in the `PendingIntent` or some other way, and then in your app, iterate over all the URLs and do whatever you want, this way having only 1 notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

EDIT: As for why nothing happens when the you cling on the notification when the app is running requires a look at how you are building the notification and possibly your activity code.

Comment: As I wrote above, I am not building the notification myself. I let Android do it for me by using the notification format. This is because the same messages are sent to iOS as well (which has some limitations in what it supports)

Comment: Can you show me how you let Android do it for you? I've never seen anything like it and i couldnt find anything on google.

Comment: All the code is above. As soon as you specify a notification payload (with body and text) in the message, Android will show the notification for you. The click_action specifies what will happen when you click it (via intent filter)

Comment: You most probably send the notification after receiving it in a service that extends `GcmListenerService`. Take a look there and see if you find how its being built. Im trying to figure out what you are using to send the notification, because it seems like a 3rd party is doing it.

Comment: No. Here's my listenerservice: public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {} - it's empty. See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en "Notification GCM automatically displays the message to end user devices on behalf of the client app. Notifications have a pre-defined set of user-visible keys.".

Comment: Oh, im really sorry, completely missed that feature. Ive been trying to figure out what could cause this problem. It seems like when the newer notification is collapsed into the old one, it forgets to update the extra `data`. The only hope i see is that maybe when the notifications are collapsed, both the payload from the old message and the new one is contained in the intent. Have you tried debugging and seing if there is something else in the intent?